# Visual Studio 2008 error:ATL

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, atl

Getting this compilation error:

> Error 4107    fatal error C1189: #error :  ATL requires C++ compilation
>   (use a .cpp suffix)   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h   59

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as the error message says. If your source file ends in `.c` the compiler assumes it's a straight C source which is incompatible with the C++ required for ATL. Change the filename to `.cpp` and it will compile.

If you really do need to stay with C then you'll have to find another library other than ATL to help you.